# Prevent Alert Dialog to dismiss on Button Clicked

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have cerated a custom Alert Dialog in my application with Some EditText, Spinner. I have used default Negative and Positive button of alert dialog.

I want to first verify the data on Positive button clicked and if everything is OK then dismiss Alert Dialog else keep the alert on and display Error message in toast.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_title_add));
    builder.setView(dialoglayout);

builder.setPositiveButton(getString(android.R.string.ok),
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
} });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you setting your built-in positive button, and it looks like you are using a custom View.

Use the button that will be clicked in your custom View just like any other button - set a click listener, and in the `onClick()` method, check to see if the EditText input is correct. Then, use your_alert.cancel() to dismiss the AlertDialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
AlertDialog alert;
builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_title_add));
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
Button your_button = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.your_button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(edittext_false){ 
                      Toast.makeText(context, "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                      alert.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }); 
alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```